Why is Microsoft Defender scanning my code every time?
this question is similar as "Why is Windows Defender scanning my code?", but worse than it. Whenever I use vscode or dev c++ run any C code, Microsoft Defender'll send the message everytime

Security Scan Required Your administrator requires a security scan of this item. The scan could take up to 10 seconds.

This situation did not happen from the beginning, it happened at this afternoon and it just don't stop. The computer is my own personal machine and my user is the admin so it shouldn't be the problem of organization.
I know   "Why is Windows Defender scanning my code?"  's answer has mentioned I can Add an exclusion. But if I need to compiling B folder, C folder ....X folder, is adding lots of exclusion the only way I can do? So I want to know if there is a better solution available.
Copying the path "D:\TDM-GCC-64\bin" to user variables from system variables (or copying "D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin" to system variables from user variables) is all I can remember. And I try to return it back but doesn't work. There is no necessity to show code because every code will cause the situation (even just Hello World).
my English is not good so if there is any impolite language, please forgive it

I find it helps to put all of your projects under one common directory so you only need to exclude that one base directory. Like dev/project1, dev/project2, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-block-at-first-sight-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide#not-an-enterprise-admin-or-it-pro may help.

@RetiredNinja    Yes, sure. it's a nice way to solve this problem . But what makes me uncomfortable is that during my previous time using vscode, I didn't need to do anything else to compile and execute successfully, so I want to know the root cause of this problem, so as to completely avoid this situation from happening. If I really can't find the source, I'll try reinstalling the system. Anyway thank you for your suggestion

I don't think this should be closed as "not about programming" (two people have cast such votes right now). this is about running programming artifacts (a built c++ binary) on the most widely used OS, dealing with an issue with its built-in antivirus.

I encounter this same problem, windows defender is wonky that way.  I have all my project subfolders in main folder PROJECTS -- and I exclude that one folder.  It's a great and simple/easy solution for a long time now.  I'm careful to NOT have any other stuff in PROJECTS besides programming, and this keeps risk small/minimal.
